# no response to HTTP POST with spark java

Tags: java, rest, spark-java

I get a response to a http POST request if I set the response to a empty String.

```
post("/hello", (request, response) -> {
        obj.toClass(request.body());
        return "";
    } );
```

However I dont get a response if I set the return statement to a non empty string (Time Out).

```
post("/hello", (request, response) -> {
        obj.toClass(request.body());
        return "Success";
    } );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. I suspect the problem is elsewhere. What's obj? What's in the body? What does the toClass method does?

Comment: Tom G., Hi I tested your issue. And for me all works as expected when rerutn "Success". In chrome there is app Postman. Try test this issue one more time with this rest client.

Comment: Works with Postman. Thanks!